# "Buffalo" query fails to return "Buffalo Exchange" from /discover endpoint

Tags: geocoding, here-api

**NOTE**: this question is specifically for support staff of the [HERE Developer API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/index.html) because they ask freemium users to post support questions on Stack Overflow rather than trying to contact them directly. If you're not a member of their staff and you're unable to help or if the question is unclear to you, don't worry about it. :)

---

For some reason the `/discover` endpoint doesn't return the `"Buffalo Exchange"` place that's at my specified coordinates, but only returns 2 localities that are much further away. This is the query that I'm using: `https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=34.003975%2C-118.484823&q=Buffalo&limit=20&apiKey=<insert API KEY>`. These are the results I currently receive:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Buffalo, NY, United States",
            "id": "here:cm:namedplace:21018816",
            "resultType": "locality",
            "localityType": "city",
            "address": {
                "label": "Buffalo, NY, United States",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "countryName": "United States",
                "stateCode": "NY",
                "state": "New York",
                "county": "Erie",
                "city": "Buffalo",
                "postalCode": "14202"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 42.88544,
                "lng": -78.87846
            },
            "distance": 3551940,
            "mapView": {
                "west": -78.9168,
                "south": 42.82603,
                "east": -78.79492,
                "north": 42.96651
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Buffalo City, Eastern Cape, South Africa",
            "id": "here:cm:namedplace:23402337",
            "resultType": "locality",
            "localityType": "city",
            "address": {
                "label": "Buffalo City, Eastern Cape, South Africa",
                "countryCode": "ZAF",
                "countryName": "South Africa",
                "state": "Eastern Cape",
                "county": "Buffalo City",
                "city": "Buffalo City",
                "postalCode": "5201"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": -33.0148,
                "lng": 27.9038
            },
            "distance": 16910944,
            "mapView": {
                "west": 27.15745,
                "south": -33.28749,
                "east": 28.08053,
                "north": -32.674
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can see that for both places the `resultType` is `"locality"`.

Now compare that to the first result of a similar query that searches for the term `"Exchange"` instead of `"Buffalo"`. All other query params are the same. This is the URL: `https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=34.003975%2C-118.484823&q=Exchange&limit=20&apiKey=<insert API KEY>`, and this is how the results begin (not shown fully because there are many results):

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "Buffalo Exchange",
            "id": "here:pds:place:8403fv6k-b15f290ec4f409deea99318f7388bbd6",
            "resultType": "place",
            "address": {
                "label": "Buffalo Exchange, 2449 Main St, Santa Monica, CA 90405, United States",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "countryName": "United States",
                "stateCode": "CA",
                "state": "California",
                "county": "Los Angeles",
                "city": "Santa Monica",
                "district": "City of Santa Monica",
                "street": "Main St",
                "postalCode": "90405",
                "houseNumber": "2449"
            },
            "position": {
                "lat": 34.00342,
                "lng": -118.48483
            },
            "access": [
                {
                    "lat": 34.00331,
                    "lng": -118.48493
                }
            ],
            "distance": 61,
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "600-6800-0090",
                    "name": "Women's Apparel",
                    "primary": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "600-6800-0000",
                    "name": "Clothing & Accessories"
                },
                {
                    "id": "600-6800-0089",
                    "name": "Men's Apparel"
                },
                {
                    "id": "600-6900-0251",
                    "name": "Used/Second-hand Merchandise Stores"
                }
            ],
            "references": [
                {
                    "supplier": {
                        "id": "core"
                    },
                    "id": "1211447153"
                },
                {
                    "supplier": {
                        "id": "yelp"
                    },
                    "id": "5PzeN6hGLBPmJpCJ2ZmfCQ"
                }
            ],
            "contacts": [
                {
                    "phone": [
                        {
                            "value": "+13103147300"
                        },
                        {
                            "value": "+13103924301",
                            "categories": [
                                {
                                    "id": "600-6800-0000"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "fax": [
                        {
                            "value": "(520) 622-7015",
                            "categories": [
                                {
                                    "id": "600-6800-0000"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "www": [
                        {
                            "value": "http://www.buffaloexchange.com",
                            "categories": [
                                {
                                    "id": "600-6800-0000"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "600-6900-0251"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "email": [
                        {
                            "value": "contact@bufex.com",
                            "categories": [
                                {
                                    "id": "600-6800-0000"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "openingHours": [
                {
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "id": "600-6800-0000"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": [
                        "Mon-Sun: 11:00 - 20:00"
                    ],
                    "isOpen": false,
                    "structured": [
                        {
                            "start": "T110000",
                            "duration": "PT09H00M",
                            "recurrence": "FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "categories": [
                        {
                            "id": "600-6800-0090"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "600-6900-0251"
                        }
                    ],
                    "text": [
                        "Mon-Sat: 11:00 - 20:00",
                        "Sun: 11:00 - 19:00"
                    ],
                    "isOpen": false,
                    "structured": [
                        {
                            "start": "T110000",
                            "duration": "PT09H00M",
                            "recurrence": "FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA"
                        },
                        {
                            "start": "T110000",
                            "duration": "PT08H00M",
                            "recurrence": "FREQ:DAILY;BYDAY:SU"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
}
```

You can see that the first result has the name `"Buffalo Exchange"` and the `"resultType"` is `"place"`. This is the result I want. The question is **why does this result fail to show up when the search query is `"Buffalo"`**? Of course with the `/discover` endpoint I can't specify the category IDs I want to search, that's only available via the `/browse` endpoint. But with the `/browse` endpoint I can't specify a specific search term like "Buffalo" or "Exchange".

**Update**: this problem also happens with the "Bison" query in Alberta, Canada. The query for this is `https://discover.search.hereapi.com/v1/discover?at=56.745531%2C-111.351341&q=Exchange&limit=20&apiKey=<insert API KEY>`. This query yields only 10 results, and only 4 of them have `resultType` of `"place"`.

Comment: Certainly there are thousands of Bison Ranches and similarly named business with Bison in them, likely in Alberta alone. There is a town named bison but not sure this is the same issue as Buffalo, as there is also 3 places named coffee in the US, and that yields results.

Comment: Hello Uche, we are looking into this issue and will get back to you the earliest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recommend application developers to use both Autosuggest and Discover, you get the nearby Buffalo Exchange because Autosuggest considers that the query is incomplete. Note that Discover considers the query to be complete.

As HERE Geocoding and Search is meant to provide relevant responses to user queries.

Geocoding Search Api (Autosuggest): https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-autosuggest-brief.html

Geocoding Search Api (Discover):  https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-discover-brief.html

The above-mentioned user guide can help modify the query for accurate results.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 2 questions: (1) is there a way to regulate how many non-place results get returned by `/autosuggest`? I'm only interested in results that have `resultType` of `place` but the API docs don't show a way to do this. The docs for `/browse` describe using category IDs for this type of filtering, is that possible for `/autosuggest` (or even `/discover`)? (2) is there a way to specify to `/discover` that my queries should not match the title exactly? So that a query like `"Buffalo"` could still match `"Buffalo Exchange"`, as an example